# Regular expression library for vc6 Cstring?

Tags: regex, open-source, visual-c++-6

Is there any regular expression library that i can use with CString of vc6?
Opensource/Free library is needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version 3.1.3 of the [Regular Expression Component Library](http://www.tropicsoft.com/Components/RegularExpression/) based on boost regex supports VC6 and even version below than that.

Answer (score 1):

Boost has some support for VC6. Be prepared to fight with the compiler every step of the way though.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/) with adaptation for CString. It has already C++ extension for *string*.